# How do I increase maximum attachment size in Exchange 2007 SP1?

Tags: powershell, exchange-2007

I've been looking all over for a relatively simple answer to a fairly straightforward question: "how do I increase the maximum size of attachments that can be sent and/or received in Exchange 2007?".  But I have yet to find a solution that works.

We have a pretty straightforward setup: Exchange 2007 SP1 running on a single server, with the OWA role delegated to a second server.  We did a clean install of Exchange 2007 a year or two ago: we **did not** upgrade from a previous version.  I forget if we installed RTM and then patched it to SP1, or if we installed with SP1 already baked in.  I just thought I'd mention those items, in case they influence the answer.

So far, I've tried running the following Powershell commands on the main Exchange server and verified that they've taken effect:

```
Set-TransportConfig -MaxReceiveSize 40MB
Set-ReceiveConnector "RcvConnector" -MaxMessageSize 40MB
Set-MaxReceiveSize "MailboxName" -MaxReceiveSize 40MB
```

As of right now, though, the specified mailbox is still rejecting messages over 10MB.

You get brownie points if you can also tell me how to set the default mailbox attachment size limits, so that new accounts don't have default **Set-MaxReceiveSize** values of "unlimited" they currently do.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Tx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to go over this MSDN article ([Managing Message Size Limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124345%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx)) that covers just about everything size & limit related in Exchange 2007.

It sounds like the Organizational limits aren't getting set correctly.  Check the Transport settings by going into the Exchange Management Console, Organization Configuration, Hub Transport, then the Global Settings tab.  The properties on the Transport settings are what I would check to see if that's causing your limits.

Answer (score 0):

I've confirmed that the limits in the **Global Settings** tab are correct.

I thought **[this article](http://exchangepedia.com/blog/2007/09/exchange-server-2007-setting-message-size.html)** stood the best chance of addressing my question.  But despite verifying that each script took effect using the **Get-TransportConfig**, **Get-ReceiveConnector**, **Get-SendConnector** and **Get-Mailbox** cmdlets, it's still not working.

FWIW, I'd be OK focusing on just increasing the max receive attachment size at first, if that simplifies things.

Comment: you've posted this an an answer to the question, where I think what you intended to do was to comment on the the other person's answer.  stack sites don't work like a normal forum.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but you may just have to restart the Microsoft Exchange Transport service.